# Rails 3: How to display many-to-many join in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, model, view

I'm trying to display all the 'legs' for each of my 'trips' in my view.

Ideally they would look like this:

```
-Trip1.name
  - Leg1.name
  - Leg2.name
  - Leg3.name
-Trip2.name
  - Leg4.name
  - Leg5.name
  - Leg6.name
```

The models are many-to-many. I have three tables Legs, Trips and Legs_trips. The models look like this:

Trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :legs
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :legs, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

Leg.rb

```
class Leg < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :trips
 validates_uniqueness_of :name
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :trips
end
```

There is nothing but this in the controller at the moment:

```
def index
@trips = Trip.all
@legs = Leg.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trips }
 end
end
```

Any suggestions for how to structure my view would be great! I've tinkered around for ages but can't seem to get anywhere near or find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <%= trip.name %>
         <% trip.legs.each do |leg| %>
            <li>
              <%= leg.name %>
            </li>
         <% end %>
     </li>
   </ul>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would be something really simple but I still spend ages on these things! Haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In you view apply them like this:

```
<ul>
<% @trips.each do |trip| %>
  <li>
  <%= tri.name %>

  <ul>
  <% @trips.legs.each do |leg_in_trip| %>
    <li>
    <%= leg_in_trip.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```