# ruby on rails -- can two Models belong to each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My group is making a Project Management System for our course, and it's my job that when a user is logged in, that they see the projects they are part of, and also that the projects listed have a members list of current members of that project.

(Also will need an add/delete member function later)

My question is, since the rest of the group have already set it up so that Projects belong to Users, is it possible to have Users belong to Projects in order to set up this member list and do what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The relation you are describing is not one-to-one:

> when **a user** is logged in, that they see **the projects** they are part of

This implies that **a user can have several projects**. You also specified:

> [project has a] list of current **members** of that project

This implies that **a projet can have several users**.

**In conclusion**, you need a **many-to-many relation** between your User and Project models.

---

This is a basic many-to-many relationship in Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects

class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  validates :user_id, :project_id, presence: true
```

- The `UserProject` model is a join table. What I have done in my code is an explicit [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference), which let you have more control over the join table. (example: add a `role` column in the `UserProject` table, containing data like `project_creator` or `simple_member`)
- The `UserProject` model could be named `Membership` to be more explicit. I used both models' name to make `UserProject`, as we usually do in Rails' naming convention.

Comment: I can understand the UserProject belonging to Project, but if UserProject is the one holding the member list (and roles), wouldn't Users need to belong to that then? Sorry if these are stupid questions. I'm really new to ruby on rails.

Comment: The class User already `has_many :user_projects` (see my code). See this link and the image which illustrate the many-to-many relationship pretty well http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: So, do I still need the third one or can't I just do the 'has_and_belongs_to_many' thing? Also, I'm still confused as to how Project gets a list of Users via UserProject? Yes it has many UserProjects, but if UserProject belongs to User and not the other way around, how can Project have many Users through UserProject? 

I'm really sorry about all this. =\

Comment: has_many :through is the better choice... maybe read up on database normalization, because that could shed some light on creating database relationships.

Comment: Have any sites or material you recommend personally? We've got less than three weeks to work on this so I'm pretty much in a rush at this point. Haha...hehe....ugh. =_="

Comment: You can use a simple `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Rails will deal with the join table by himself and you won't have to worry about it. Just type `rails habtm` in google and you will find plenty of documentation, guides and tutorials!\

Comment: Would using the :through method using the third UserProject model be a good idea for when I need to put in a deleta and add function?

Comment: no, the delete/add function will just `INSERT` or `DELETE` rows in the UserProject table

Comment: So I'm modifying the UserProject table? Ok, so let me see if I got this. I create a UserProject model, and add a belongs_to, like you've shown, along with a validation for project name and user name right? So is this table actually stored in the UserProject? I've been reading up on it but it's still all so confusing.

Comment: The UserProject table should contain only a `user_id` and a `project_id` (and its own `id`). The project's name should be stored in the Project table, user's name stored in the User table.

Comment: So having user_id and project_id is just an universal thing? Thought it was meant to point specifically to a user_id/project_id string or int value within those two tables?

Comment: Take a look at this image, it explains everything. `assemblies_parts` is `user_projects` in your case. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/habtm.png

Comment: I remember that, yes. What I'm asking is if these id numbers are inherent or are they declared variables, such that when working with newly created projects/users, they do not have an id number in the scope of this project, so would I then need to use the string names, or...are the id integers simply assigned behind the scene and working with that?

Comment: they are assigned behing, Rails deals with it pretty well

Comment: So to double check, here's what I have to do: I create a UserProject model, adding in two int values (user_id and project_id), then do two migrations (like AddUserprojectRefToUser and AddUserprojectRefToProject), add the has_many and belongs to lines where needed, and that's how I set up the database relation right? But since this project doesn't use routes files, could I be able to add and delete users to lists without using routes?

Comment: this post might help http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/ and this one too http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many also this one for the view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343365/rails-3-how-to-display-many-to-many-join-in-view

Comment: Early you mentioned that having add/delete functions would be a bad idea 'since it would delete rows'? It's part of what I gotta do for, because each project's user list needs to be added to.